# iOS Google App Engine Mobile Backend starter

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, mobile, backend

I have a few questions on Google's App Engine Mobile Backend Starter. The starter tutorial gives a sample client app but I am confused on how to build my own application to use Google's app engine mobile backend starter. Am I supposed to extend off the Object C code given in the sample app? Or is this [documentation of the API](https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/mobile-backend-starter-api-reference) sufficient to start my own app from scratch? Does anyone have any links to tutorials on things like this? The ones provided by google do not seem to be very helpful in these regards.

Comment: You're pointing to Java doc, which is for building the server side 'app'.

Comment: Actually I believe it's the api for android clients to use the mobile back end. I couldn't find the ios one

Comment: You're right.  I did something in Java on GAE server side, seeing Java triggered me.